# Easiest way to get GRUB bootloader to appear first

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, bootloader

so here's my problem. I'm running a dual boot Win8/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS setup, I forgot to install the GRUB bootloader when I was partitioning for the Ubuntu 14.10 installation. This forces me to boot into Windows 8 first every time I turn on my computer and then I have to search for advanced start up options and boot from the USB (which apparently has Ubuntu on it?). Either way, it's getting pretty freaking irritating as Windows runs so very very slow, and I would like my default to be Ubuntu. What is the easiest way I could get GRUB to run first as opposed to windows?

Again this is for a Windows 8/Ubuntu 14.04 LTS setup on a Toshiba Qosmio X875

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 4):

You need to boot from a LiveCD / USB.  Once you are booted to it, you need to open a terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.  Once your terminal is open, type in the following to get a listing of your hard drive(s) in your system:

```
sudo blkid
```

You might see something like this:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="A0F0582EF0580CC2" TYPE="ntfs" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="8c2da865-13f4-47a2-9c92-2f31738469e8" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: UUID="5641913f-9bcc-4d8a-8bcb-ddfc3159e70f" TYPE="swap"
```

As you can see here that the `/dev/sda2` is where the Ubuntu is installed by the `TYPE="ext4"` format of the partition.  To install the `grub`, we are going to mount that partition.  From the terminal window, type in:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda2 /mnt
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
```

Then we are going to switch over to the drive so we can install `grub`.  Type in the terminal window:

```
sudo chroot /mnt
```

Now, we are going to install grub to the first drive, which should be `/dev/sda`.  Type in at the terminal window:

```
grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then we need to update grub to make it the bootable MBR.  Type in:

```
update-grub
```

you should see output similar to:

```
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-37-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sda1
done
```

Then all we have to do is unmount everything and reboot the host back to the hard drive.  It should default to `grub2` when booting back up.

```
exit
sudo umount /mnt/sys
sudo umount /mnt/proc
sudo umount /mnt/dev/pts
sudo umount /mnt/dev
sudo umount /mnt
sudo reboot
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. I don't know why so few upvotes. Very useful.

Answer (score 0):

Through bios/uefi setup you could select first boot device.

or you use the "select boot device" hotkey of your bios/uefi manufacturer (normally f8 or f12)

Comment: Funny, because I tried that, and it still did not work post installation....I'm running a Toshiba Qosmio x875

Comment: what do you select in windows to boot linux?

Comment: change advanced startup options...then I go to advanced restart, select usb, and hit ubuntu, and it boots Grub.

Comment: And in uefi boot select - is no usb selectable?

Comment: USB is selectable, but it's weird. No USB is plugged in, it just knows that I booted Ubuntu from the USB and installed it on the second hard drive and boots automatically to there.

Comment: Than it needs to be grub installed to the partition where ubuntu is installed to.

Comment: via the above suggestion?

Comment: Yeah @Terrance solution should than be it...

Comment: Most important is that you install grub to the right partition - so prior installation check which partition is the ubuntu partition with gparted disks or fdisk -l