# How can I remove a bad program without logging in?

Tags: boot, recovery-mode, 20.04

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04. I decided to install `indicator-multiload`. When I had tried to install it on Ubuntu 18.whatever, it had caused me to get logged out whenever I tried to log in. I was hoping it would work in the new release, but instead it froze the entire shell and is now preventing me from logging in again. In the previous version, I just logged in with recovery mode and uninstalled the package. However, in the new version, I have no option to log in with recovery mode when I start the computer. Instead, regular Ubuntu starts instantly. I have tried holding SHIFT while booting. How can I cleanse my computer of `indicator-multiload`?

I wish I could give specifics about the affected computer, but I can't access its information right now because I can't log in. It is an old Toshiba laptop from 2014 or so.

Comment: I believe you can use your Live USB and chroot your drive to remove the application.  See:  https://askubuntu.com/a/627904/231142

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved my problem by changing my shell to Unity in the login screen, logging in, and running `sudo apt purge indicator-multiload`. I could then log back in with a different shell.